# How to interpet RFC data format

Tags: protocols

I'm having slight problems reading the used format in an Internet-Draft: [TokenBindingProtocol#Section6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-popov-token-binding-00#section-6)

here

```
enum {
   provided_token_binding(0), referred_token_binding(1), (255)
} TokenBindingType;
```

im not sure what the 255 stands for. I assume that these enum values are in the range from 0...255 i.e. represented by an 8 bit value?

```
struct {
    TokenBindingID tokenbindingid;
    opaque signature<0..2^16-1>;
    Extension extensions<0..2^16-1>;
} TokenBinding;
```

here its absolutely not clear how to interpet the <0..2^16-1> suffix.
I think it is some kind of size indicator, i.e. the value of *signature* can have a maximum length of 2^16-1 but am not sure... Also for the *extensions* field which references the struct *Extension* it's unclear. In my eyes it could mean the *extensions* field references 0 up to 2^16-1 extensions, or the sum of all extension data is up to 2^16-1

Also I could not find any document explaining this format. Is it like well known pseudo-code or are there any resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [vector](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.3) of specified size. I think everything you needed is [documented here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4).

Comment: thanks! little weird that this is described in the TLS RFC though

Comment: It took me a bit to find but I've seen similar with other RFCs so I had a clue.